# java - Framework for GroupBy

Tags: java, aggregate

In java, am looking for a framework to perform grouping of POJO based on certain properties of the class.

E.g: cooked up simple example

```
Salary {
int userId;
Double salary;
String office;
}
```

Aggregation 1: Get avg of salary in an office.

Aggregation 2: Sum of all salaries

Aggregation 3: Sum of salaries by office

Comment: *"..am looking for a framework.."* Best of luck with that, but OT for SO.

Comment: Replace the word "framework" with "solution" and the question is not off-topic anymore.  Moreover it would allow answers that solve the problem without third-party libraries or frameworks.  See Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/

About Lambdaj:

lambdaj is designed to easily manipulate collections. Its features are intended to filter, convert, index and aggregate the items of a collection without explicitly iterate on it.

For your example ;

Salary.java

```
package x;

public class Salary {
    int userId;
    Double salary;
    String office;
    public Salary(int userId, Double salary, String office) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.office = office;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public Double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(Double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String getOffice() {
        return office;
    }
    public void setOffice(String office) {
        this.office = office;
    }


}
```

LambdaX.java

```
package x;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;

import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*;

public class LambdajX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Salary> salaries = new ArrayList<Salary>();
        salaries.add(new Salary(1, 100.0, "mexico"));
        salaries.add(new Salary(2, 130.0, "germany"));
        salaries.add(new Salary(3, 190.0, "mexico"));

        LambdajX lambdajX = new LambdajX();

        System.out.println("Total Salary : "
                + lambdajX.getAggregateSalary(salaries));
        System.out.println("Total Salary in Mexico : "
                + lambdajX.getAggregateSalaryByOffice(salaries, "mexico"));

        System.out.println("Avg Salary : "
                + lambdajX.getAverageSalary(salaries));

        System.out.println("Avg Salary in Mexico :"
                + lambdajX.getAverageSalaryByOffice(salaries, "mexico"));

    }

    public Double getAggregateSalary(List<Salary> salaries) {
        return sum(salaries, on(Salary.class).getSalary());
    }

    public Double getAggregateSalaryByOffice(List<Salary> salaries,
            String office) {

        return sumFrom(
                select(salaries,
                        having(on(Salary.class).getOffice(),
                                Matchers.equalTo(office)))).getSalary();

    }

    public Double getAverageSalary(List<Salary> salaries) {
        return avg(salaries, on(Salary.class).getSalary());
    }

    public Double getAverageSalaryByOffice(List<Salary> salaries, String office) {

        return avgFrom(
                select(salaries,
                        having(on(Salary.class).getOffice(),
                                Matchers.equalTo("mexico")))).getSalary();

    }
}
```

Library Used : lambdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar

You can download this jar file from http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar

The other alternative is Guava by google.

Comment: Thanks this seems very useful. To take this to the next level: Is there a way to get the result back instead of primitive types into an user object (Say AggregatedSalary and say the key is more than one property (userId,office) for one example and (office,maleOrFemale) for another example?

Comment: You can see having clause in sumFrom. You can add multiple having using logical operator e.g. having().add(having()).or(having()). Please refer this presentation. It might help you. http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-javaone-slides.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). It's [Multimaps.index](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html) method can group POJOs into a multimap. Then you can use [Maps.transformValues](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#transformValues%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) to aggregate the values of those multimaps to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider two frameworks myBatis and Hibernate.
About myBatis, I think it is suitable to your case because you can write SQL statement directly and it is also easy to support mapping SQL results to Java object through out xml file.
[MyBatis sample](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your questions. Actually I haven't hear and used any framework which can aggregate POJO objects. In my projects, I always handle the aggregation by code in service layers.